# How to compile the new version of glibc under Raspberry Pi 4 and cross compile a simple project

Tags: windows, eclipse, glibc, raspberry-pi4

I am using a raspberry pi 4 to test the cross-compilation and run the code I compiled on a windows machine under eclipse using a cross-compiler.

When I downloaded the latest version of the cross toolchain from the ARM developer, I faced a non-compatibility between the glibc I had in my toolchain and the glibc I have in my Rasberry pi 4 board.

I tired solve this issue I tried to download the glibc 2.34 and compile it into my Rasberry pi 4 board.

I have followed this tutorial (How to build and use glibc for):

[http://www.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/kml/how_to_build_and_use_glibc.html](http://www.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Etosh/kml/how_to_build_and_use_glibc.html)

After the installation process, I have the following files in my local folder in the Rasberry pi board:

`/usr/local/lib/glib-testing/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`

`/usr/local/lib/glib-testing/lib/libc.so.6`

`/usr/local/lib/glib-testing/lib/libc.so`

`/usr/local/lib/glib-testing/lib/libc.a`

In my host machine under Windows 10 I am using eclipse.

I looked at the same example and question in the StackOverflow forum and I tried to inspire by them.

for example this question: [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) have a lot of similitude but still have some issues running my application on the PI since I am compiling on Windows.

I added the following lines to my eclipse linker to pointe to the library I installed in my local folder:

`-Wl,--rpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Arm_GNU_Toolchain_aarch64-none-linux-gnu\12.2 rel1\lib" -Wl,--dynamic-linker="/usr/local/lib/glibc-testing/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1"`

When I run the code I have this message:

`/home/pi/Bookshelf/Software/raspberyPi4TestCrossCompilation: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

```
I don't want to copy the files in the system because I have seen people saying taht it's dangerous and it can destroy my system. That's why I want to understand before doing bullshit.
```

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: Did you try to define the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Anyway I had the same problem and found that instead of building the newest glibc on the R-Pi, better to downgrade the build machine. On Linux with the help of Docker it is easy task. Pull the `debian:bullseye`. The rest works out of the box.